# How to append to the current position of a HTML range element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to append a small image to the progress bar of a video on my webpage so that users can "pin" certain points in the video to come back to later. Is there a way to use Jquery to append to the current position of the slider in an HTML range element?

Basically, what I am trying to do is append a pin image to the slider bar at the current position of the slider, but I'm not sure how to access it.

[image]

I already have the progress bar working and I know how to append elements to handles. I just don't know of a way to find the id of the little slider on the progress bar.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear on the question. If I understand you, you want to access the slider handle on the range input. The handle from the slider is part of the Shadow Dom and is not directly accessible, but you can get to it with css like so:

```
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {...}
```

Check out [this article](https://glazkov.com/2011/01/14/what-the-heck-is-shadow-dom/) for more info